# How Microk8s works with Swap Partition

Tags: linux, swap, microk8s

Since the Kubenetes Version 1.27, **kubelet** doesn't work with *Swap Partition* enabled machine. How the **microk8s** handles it?

I understand that **minikube** creates a virtual environment and configures the control_plane & worker nodes accordingly, but how **microk8s** overcame this issue? 
Thanks !